# SVN Checkout how to restrict acces only to users

Tags: svn

i have a project in my SVN :), thats been active for some time.

How ever, i only want people in my company to have acces to check out.

It's not using apache, plain svn+ssh.

Right now only my users can do a commit, i uncommented the line in **conf/svnserve.conf**:

```
password-db = passwd
```

and i wrote a list of users and passwords in the **conf/passwd** file

It works for commit, since it asks for user and password when a user commits.

I need it to do the same for a check out.

I hope i was able to explain such a simple problem y such a complicated way ja!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html

Add this line to your svnserv.conf

anon-access = none

If you want people to authenticate to checkout.

Comment: SO wierd, wont work. I add the line to the repository located in: /var/svn-repos/catwizard3/conf, then i stop the svn server killing the process by id, then a start it again with svnserve -d -T -r /var/svn-repos/, then i try to do a ckeck from a new folder on my local machine, and it starts downloading the code.

Comment: Can you try it from a remote machine? Do you have certificate authentication turned on? Are you checking out using svn co svn+ssh://localhost or just pointing towards the repo?

Comment: I tried out from a remote machine, you were right, it must be some certificate turned one or something. Thank you